# Can an SSD locked by ATA password be formatted with Diskpart "Clean" command? And would that erase the ATA password?

Tags: ssd, passwords, diskpart, ata

Can an SSD locked by ATA password be formatted with Diskpart "Clean" command?

If the answer is “Yes,” does the formatting also erase the ATA password?

Comment: Have you at least tried it?

Answer (score 2):

No, because the diskpart "clean" command is not implemented as an ATA Secure Erase - it just [zeroes the drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/clean) (if the "all" parameter is specified).

If you do not know the existing password, the only way to perform any operation on an SSD locked with a password is to initiate a Secure Erase with a new (known to you) erase password. This resets any previous password and wipes the drive. By design, the drive cannot be used until the wipe actually completes.

In other words, barring flaws in the ATA implementation, the only way to return a drive with an unknown password to service is to lose everything that was on it. This is a feature.

Tools to do this usually require booting from other media, and include Linux `hdparm` (part of many Linux live images) and Hughes' [HDDErase](https://cmrr.ucsd.edu/resources/secure-erase.html) (DOS-based - needs a DOS bootable image)

Comment: That's a pretty big 'if', though. I rather doubt it is implemented as ATA Secure Erase, mainly because most BIOSes send the "security lockout" command to all internal disks on startup so the OS can't control that anymore...

Comment: @u1686_grawity - very good point - it only zeroes! Updated to reflect this nuance.

Comment: According to docs doesn't even do that; it only removes the partition table information. I *think* it might actually zero SSDs when they support the 'trim/discard' operation (i.e. without requiring to manually write zeros to each sector), but I know it doesn't do "manual" zeroing purely because of how quick it is.

Comment: @u1686_grawity the additional parameter "all" does the zeroing. Updating to clarify.